# Static WCF service client object or standard WCF service client object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, static-methods, static-members

I am developing a website in ASP.NET that uses a WCF service. I am creating the service client object using following approach:

> I am using a Global class file to define these methods.

```
public static WCore.Service1Client client;
public static int ConnectToWCore()
{
    try
    {
       client = new WCore.Service1Client();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, is it correct to use static client object on a website? Because I am in a confusion that it can have deadlock problems, because many users will be accessing same object as the static objects are created once and are common to all instances. Please tell me which one will be efficient Static object or Standard one?

Answer (score 2):

The WCF clients are meant to be lightweight and created wherever they are needed. Unless you have actually measured performance problems from creating multiple client objects, you should do that.

Also using error code return values is not the right way to handle errors in C#. C# uses exception and that's what all C# code should prefer to use.

Comment: But I want to know that which is more efficient in case of performance? using the same static client or different objects for different users? What will be your suggestion, what should I use finally for a website with multiple concurrent users?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using a static service client for WCF is a good move, as I have seen that in almost all instances it is created when needed, and then disposed of.

Correct me if I am wrong but persisting the service client is wasteful of resources and opens up opportunities for various problems, such as session loss, timeouts as well as others. It is the usual practice to create them on demand, do your business then dispose of the object.

Also, I think ASP websites are "instanced" between clients, with each client having their own separate copy of the same website. Thus you may run into more issues with multiple clients trying to access the same service client at once.

Comment: No, ASP web sites are not "instanced" per client. There is only one website. What may differ is that the server launches multiple threads (or multiple instances of the same process) to process each incoming request, but the contents of the web site are the same.